# Query document in list - spring data mongodb

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I have the following object:

```
{ 
   "id" : "sampleId";
   foos : [{
         "prop1":"value1",
         "prop2":"value2"
      },
      {
         "prop1":"value3", 
         "prop2":"value4"
      }
]}
```

How can I get `foos`, where `prop2` is `value4`? I'm using Spring data mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

If you use spring data mongodb repositories, it can make your life easy. You will need a domain class. e.g.

```
public class Foo {
    String prop1;
    String prop2;
}

public class MyClass {
    String id;
    List<Foo> foos;
}

public interface MyClassRepository extends MongoRepository<MyClass, String> {
    List<MyClass> findByFoosProp2(String prop2ValueToLookFor);
    // assuming you can find multiple matches
}
```

Then simply call this method from your code

```
public clsss SomeBusinessClass {
    @Autowired
    private MyClassRepository repository;

    public void mySomeBusinessMethod() {
        List<MyClass> myObjects = repository.findByFoosProp2("value4");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will return a SampleBean with id sampleId wich will have only matching items in collection foos.

```
// Match one document with sampleId
Query q1 = new Query(where("id").is("sampleId"));

// match only foos with prop2 value value2 
Query q2 = query(where("foos").elemMatch(where("prop2").is("value2))

BasicQuery query = new BasicQuery(q1.getQueryObject(), q2.getQueryObject());
SampleBean result = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, SampleBean.class)
```